# Getting all values (selected and not selected )from html multilist

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two html multi lists List1 and List2.
List1 contains all the attributes of a table from DB. Now I have buttons Add, AddAll which will take data from list1 to list2. Now I wants to pass the attributes which are added in list2 to another .jsp page on submit. 
How can i do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

ON your form onsubmit action, call javascript function. 
That function will read values from list2 ( innerHtml), make a string of all the values concatinated with some special values and set this string to hidden field of form.

This way you have all the element of list2 on your jsp page.

Comment: Alright. if this helped you then please accept this answer so the other people get benefited.